# Adding new columns to a dataset by matching two row names, and adding information from one correlated name to the other

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a bit confused on how to perform this form of data wrangling, as I am new to R coding. My goal is to match subjectID information to this large data set that I have that have more rows than that of the subjectID data. This is because the large data has more than one session with a cohort of subjects. For example,Subject A would have data that has a row name SubjectA-01, SubjectA-02, SubjectB-1202, SubjectB-W2D1, etc.

My goal is to match SubjectID name to the large data set, such that I can add new columns (sex, age, BMI, etc.) as columns correlating to the data.

**We can call this dataframe as SubjectInfo**

| Subject ID | Sex | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SubjectA | M | 32 |
| SubjectC | F | 23 |
| SubjectB | F | 16 |

And I want to use this information to match the beginning keyword in this matrix. **Let's call this data set as BioResults.**

| SampleID | Blood Result |
| --- | --- |
| SubjectC-GH21 | 2.22 |
| SubjectA-01 | 2.34 |
| SubjectA-02 | 2.55 |
| SubjectB-12 | 3.56 |

My goal is to make a new data set that looks like this:

| SampleID | Blood Result | Sex | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SubjectC-GH21 | 2.22 | F | 23 |
| SubjectA-01 | 2.34 | M | 32 |
| SubjectA-0122 | 2.55 | M | 32 |
| SubjectB-Q32 | 3.56 | F | 16 |

I was told a way to address this would be by doing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

BioResults %>% mutate(ID = str_remove(SampleID, '-.*')) %>% 
       inner_join(subjectInfo, by = c('ID' = 'SubjectID')) %>% select(-ID)
```

However, I still seem to have difficulty reproducing the desired results. Is there another way to do this? I know the first step to address this would be to remove the dash symbol (-) and any characters after that, so I can match the the SubjectInfo row names to that in the BioResults table, and create new columns to pair sex and age to each row.

I would appreciate any help working on this. I did see other Stack Overflow discussions on data manipulation using `left_join`, `right_join`, etc. but I still seem to struggle with this set of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution:

- For this purpose I first created a new variable `SampleID2` out of `SampleID` column of data set two by omitting the suffix parts of values
- After they contents of `Subject_ID` have become more alike we can bind the two data set together

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>%
  mutate(SampleID2 = gsub("(Subject\\w)-.*", "\\1", SampleID)) %>%
  full_join(DF, by = c("SampleID2" = "Subject_ID")) %>%
  select(-SampleID2)

       SampleID Blood_Result Sex Age
1 SubjectC-GH21         2.22   F  23
2   SubjectA-01         2.34   M  32
3   SubjectA-02         2.55   M  32
4   SubjectB-12         3.56   F  16
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)

# Sample data
SubjectInfo <- fread("SubjectID     Sex     Age
SubjectA    M   32
SubjectC    F   23
SubjectB    F   16")
BioResults <- fread("SampleID   Blood_Result
SubjectC-GH21   2.22
SubjectA-01     2.34
SubjectA-02     2.55
SubjectB-12     3.56")
# or setDT(SubjectInfo);setDT(BioResults)

# create a temporary column to join on
BioResults[, SubjectID := gsub("(^Subject[A-Z]).*", "\\1", SampleID)]
#         SampleID Blood_Result SubjectID
# 1: SubjectC-GH21         2.22  SubjectC
# 2:   SubjectA-01         2.34  SubjectA
# 3:   SubjectA-02         2.55  SubjectA
# 4:   SubjectB-12         3.56  SubjectB

# perform join
BioResults[SubjectInfo, `:=`(Sex = i.Sex, Age = i.Age), on = .(SubjectID)]

#drop the temporary column
BioResults[, SubjectID := NULL]
#         SampleID Blood_Result Sex Age
# 1: SubjectC-GH21         2.22   F  23
# 2:   SubjectA-01         2.34   M  32
# 3:   SubjectA-02         2.55   M  32
# 4:   SubjectB-12         3.56   F  16
```